# In Android, how to force the native code to use my version of a shared library, instead of the system's?

Tags: android, android-ndk, linker, shared-libraries, pcre

Android already has the PCRE shared library ("/system/lib/libpcre.so"), but it's compiled without Unicode support, so I've built my own version of PCRE for Android. My native code is linked to the PCRE shared library. However, when I run my app, it uses the system's version of PCRE, rather than the one I've built, even though my APK does include my version of PCRE. How do I make it use my version of PCRE rather than the system's? Generally in Linux I use "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" or "RPATH", but on Android I don't know how to use them, if that's at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `load("your-path-to-lib")` before you load the main library. With [this API](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#load(java.lang.String)) you can load a native library at arbitrary location. But the easiest way is to rely on the default behavior of build and installer, which will pack the native libraries (named **`lib`*something*`.so`**) that it finds in `libs/<ABI>` folders, into the APK file, and unpack the ABI variant that matches the target into

```
getContext().getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir
```

(this was added in *API level 9*)

If the library is pre-loaded, you cannot have your library side-by-side with the system one, due to a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6670) that invloved older versions of Android. Still, you may succeed to unload it manually, using `dlclose()`:

```
handle = dlopen("<libname>", RTLD_NOLOAD);
dlclose(handle);
dlclose(handle); // twice, because dlopen() increments ref count
```

You will probably do these manipulations in a separate small `dlclose_helper.so`. Load this helper load before you load the main library, which needs the private version of `<libname>`.

A fix was introduced for API level 23 that lets us finally load both `dir1/libx.so` and `dir2/libx.so` (see the [official doc](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md#Correct-soname_path-handling-Available-in-API-level-23)).

Note that for API level 24, [new restrictions](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md#private-api-enforced-for-api-level-24) have also been introduced that limits access to system libraries (you can only load white-listed ones).

Comment: And what is the path to my library?

Comment: Sorry, I meant [load()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#load(java.lang.String)) (*fixed in the answer*).

Comment: Thanx, but I'm afraid it doesn't work. I made sure that my "libpcre.so" actually resides in `getContext().getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir`, and that I `load` it before the main library, and yet, the system "libpcre.so" is used.

Comment: which ROM are you using? I know that libpcre was included as external in API v. 20, but I have not yet seen it preinstalled on a real device

Comment: *before* you load your native code, check with `cat /proc/<pid>/maps` if `/system/lib/libpcre.so` is loaded into your process. If it is, you cannot seamlessly replace it with your variant. You will have to **a)** change its soname (e.g. `libpcre1.so`), and **b)** rebuild the depending modules to rely on `libpcre1`.

Comment: I don't know what u mean by ROM, but I'm running the app on my Nexus 5 phone, which runs Android 5.1.1 (API level 22).

Comment: I've checked "/proc/<pid>/maps" and it indeed contains "/system/lib/libpcre.so". So, if I want to change the 
"soname", is it possible to do it after the "so" was built, or I must create it with the desired "soname" in the first place?

Comment: Right, I see that on 5.1, the *zigote* process (and hence all user apps) have  `/system/lib/libpcre.so` preloaded. Now you have a deeper problem with your code that depends on a "better" PCRE. The problem is, how will the system loader know to call `pcre2_code_free()` from your library and not from the system library?

Comment: I have not tried this, but maybe (if RTLD_NODELETE was not used to load it), you can `dlclose()` the system instance of libpcre.

Comment: But `dlclose` requires the handle from `dlopen`, and I don't have it.

Comment: `dlopen("/system/lib/libpcre.so", RTLD_NOLOAD)` will give you the current handle

Comment: I didn't believe this would work, but it did! Android ignores "RTLD_NOLOAD", so I when I called "dlopen" it actually incremented the library reference count, and so I had to call "dlclose" twice! Many thanks! Btw I don't feel comfortable with hardcoding the path for "/system/lib/libpcre.so". Is there a way to get directory(ies) where system libraries reside?

Comment: First of all, I am glad this helped. Second, <s>I think</s> `RTLD_NOLOAD` is expected to increment the ref count, see http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2013-10/msg00742.html. Finally, you can check your `/proc/<pid>/maps` to find the path, or simply `dlopen("libpcre.so")`, because `/system/lib` is on the **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** always. I will update my answer.

Comment: Well, if `RTLD_NOLOAD` does increment the ref count, I don't understand what it does. Anyway you're right - simply `dlopen("libpcre.so")` worked. I'll add a detailed answer based on your suggestions. Thanx a lot!

Comment: `RTLD_NOLOAD` does not load a module that is not already loaded

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way is to rename the library (libpcre_myapp, for example).

Note that renaming just the file probably is not sufficient, but changing the SO_NAME ELF property.

Comment: Simply renaming the "so" doesn't work, I have to edit the PCRE build system to initially produce an "so" with a different name. As I use many libraries, I have to do that for every library that I build, and this becomes a nuisance. I really would hope there's a better solution.

Comment: Ah, right. There's a SO_NAME property of the library, and I think that is what actually has to be unique from the platform library. Another solution might be to directly dlopen your library rather than linking it dynamically, but I'm less sure about that.